# Var in extension class show error "Extensions must not contain stored properties"

Tags: ios, swift, class, properties, var

Since I have many vars and I would like put in new file. When I move var to new file in extension, I got error "Extensions must not contain stored properties". How can I solve it? What is best way to "Clean up" var? Here my code:

Class:

```
class ReminderMain: UIViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      //Do something
   }
}
```

Extension:

```
extension ReminderMain {
   var greeting = UILabel()
}
```

Comment: As the error states clearly, you can't move "vars" to an extension.

Comment: If I want clean up the var, what is best other method do that?

Comment: One approach is to use a helper class.  The view controller still keeps all the UI outlets but any work or variables concerning view state move to the helper.

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to put `greeting` in a new file?  It is pretty normal for view controllers to contain variables at the class level, especially if they need to be evaluated or used by multiple functions.   Extensions can contain computed properties, functions, and other types of code, but not actual stored properties.

Comment: I know, but I have like over 100 vars or more, you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually need is to follow an architecture for your project like `MVC`, `MVP` or `MVVM` these are the popular ones (there are many more). These architecture enable you to clean up your code and maintain a structure for your project.

Now for you scenario that you have explained above, you seem to have many stored properties like `var greeting = UILabel()` you might wanna move them into a view class and use only one view to set the view of the controller. Here's an example (in MVC):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let myView = View()
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        view = myView
        myView.model = Model(greetingText: "My greeting")
    }
}

class View: UIView {
    var model: Model? {
        didSet { greeting.text = model?.greetingText }
    }
    var greeting = UILabel()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(greeting)
        // add all other sub-views and layout them here
    }
}
struct Model { var greetingText: String }
```

For more details about refactoring go through tutorials that explain this much better and in detail.